# Formatting Output of Input Statement

Tags: python

I would like to format this output in a way where the numbers in parenthesis are even and line up in a straight line with the other numbers in parenthesis.. Example output shown below

```
# AStE ....................(1)
# AST......................(2)
#ZASKW.....................(3)
#gREEENN...................(4)
# THESE ARE EXAMPLE NAMES WITH MORE LETTERS IN THEM.



location = raw_input("\n \n THIS IS A LIST OF words with ID'S ASSIGNED TO THEM () \n ASTE (1)\n Ast (2) \n AS (3) \n ASTO (4) \n Bro (5) \n Cor (6) \n DUn (7) \n DUNWO (8) \n Ea (9) \n Eas (10) \n"" VI (11) \n Green (12) \n Mill (13) \n State (14) \n Ver (15) \n We (16) \n PLEASE ENTER THE ID # ")
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, what should happen if a number in parenthesis is 10 or greater--are those numbers to be left-aligned, right-aligned, or other? Why do the `AStE` and `AST` lines have a leading space but the other lines do not? You must make your problem statement more clear.

Comment: My goal is to try to line up the parenthesis so if there was a location name with a lot of letters, it would line up appropriately. Any way I could do that. I am trying it to do it manually but it's not efficient

Comment: In computer programming, vague words like "appropriately" are not appropriate. You cannot communicate a concept to a computer if you do not understand it yourself. Work out the details yourself before you try to get a computer to do it for you. I am not writing this to shame you but to encourage you to work harder on the preliminaries of programming--understanding the problem clearly and specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should do what you wish.

```
commands = ["AStE", "AST", "ZASKW", "gREEENN"]
max_columns = 30

for index, commands in enumerate(commands):
    stars_amount = max(max_columns - len(commands), 0)
    row = "# {} {}({})".format(commands, "." * stars_amount, index + 1)
    print row
print "PLEASE ENTER THE ID:"
```

Output:

```
# AStE ..........................(1)
# AST ...........................(2)
# ZASKW .........................(3)
# gREEENN .......................(4)
PLEASE ENTER THE ID:
```

An alternative solution based on @asongtoruin comment:

```
commands = ["AStE", "AST", "ZASKW", "gREEENN"]

for index, commands in enumerate(commands):
    row = "# {:.<30} ({})".format(commands, index + 1)
    print row
print "PLEASE ENTER THE ID:"
```

Comment: You could do this more neatly with [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)